# "Uncapable" or "incapable"?

Tags: word-choice, orthography, negation, prefixes

In Microsoft Word, *uncapable* is marked as wrong. It sounded pretty alright to me, thus, I checked it up on the Web and found that many dictionaries do not have "uncapable" in their entries, but dictionaries such as [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncapable) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncapable) list it to be a synonym of *incapable*. My question is: is *uncapable* considered a "proper" word?

Comment: I've heard both frequently, but only use "incapable" myself. I dare say that someone will invent a (spurious) rule for the difference, one day, based on his personal preferences. That's how it usually works.

Comment: Which has always puzzled me - who comes up with all these words?

Comment: Usually, they're mis-association of things that are common in other words.  A great example is "inflammable" (= can catch fire), where large numbers of people assumed that the "in" was a prefix of negation, and used it to mean fireproof.  The thing is: if enough people get it wrong, there's a chance that they're right to, and the word needed improvement.  (That doesn't stop me hissing and spitting when it happens, though.)

Comment: I personally use “uncapable” if I am using it to describe generalized trait of a person rather than to describe a specific lack of capacity, more like a synonym of incompeten. E.g. “I fired my assistant because he was a very lazy and uncapable person,” as opposed to “I fired my assistant because he was incapable of being punctual.” I don’t have a cite for this, but I have a sense that that’s how I’ve seen it used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a dictionary has it, that dictionary is just trying to be so comprehensive as to include any word ever.  However, *incapable* is the proper and original form, and furthermore, [everyone uses it](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=uncapable,incapable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  I have never seen *uncapable* in use.

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=uncapable%2Cincapable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

The rule of thumb to go by is: If you're choosing between variants of a word, pick the variant most widely used and understood.  So when you have to choose, choose *incapable*.

Comment: Much appreciated :) I do see uncapable in common use nowadays though, perhaps not so much in literary texts.

Comment: In what country and among what level of education? In google it is 300k versus 34mio

Comment: I can't recall ever seeing `uncapable` used.

Comment: @Ted: Same here.  Oh yes, I already said that, didn't I?

Answer (score 1):

I came to this site because I ran across the word uncapable in the writings of Mother Theresa.  She speaks of God talking to her about becoming a sister of the poor.  "You are I know the most uncapable person, weak and sinful, but just because you are that I want to use you, For My Glory! Wilt thou refuse?"  Unable, unsuited, unskilled, unfit, unqualified are all synonyms of incapable.  But somehow this non-word, uncapable, has a sense of a void or emptiness waiting to be filled, rather than the feeling of incompetence that the word incapable gives.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the word "incapable" [dates from 1600](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=incapable).

At that time, when picking the latinate prefix to indicate negation, whoever coined the word went with "in," not "un." A lot of words follow the pattern, e.g., "incredible," "inconceivable," which also date from the same period.

Once that form became set and fixed, there was no need for a version with "un-." I would flag "uncapable" as an error in a text and correct it, unless the term was being used for a special purpose, which could happen in an academic text.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done a [google ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Incapable%2Cuncapable&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1400&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CIncapable%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bincapable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIncapable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuncapable%3B%2Cc0) for 'uncapable' vs 'incapable' and was surprised to see a short period in the late 17th century when they were just about equally common.

'Uncapable' has virtually disappeared from normal usage since then but don't forget that Mother Theresa was Albanian and learned her English in an Irish convent. Maybe Irish nuns have preserved some Commonwealth and late Stuart language forms that the rest of us have forgotton!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer that *incapable* is the best word for most occasions. However, a small note about the **history and "wordness" of *uncapable***:

According to the OED's attestations, ***un***capable actually slightly predates ***in***capable (1586<sup>1</sup> vs 1597<sup>2</sup>, respectively). In fact, there are five separate examples of *uncapable* from the sixteenth century, and only one of *incapable*.

Both words apparently existed side-by-side for a while—perhaps a century or so, if the OED and [Google Book's Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uncapable%2Cincapable&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuncapable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincapable%3B%2Cc0) viewer are anything to go by. However, in the eighteenth century the *in* version became firmly established, while the *un* version fell out of vogue and is by now generally obsolete:

The last attestation in the OED for *uncapable* is 1805, from a translation of Dante's *Inferno*, though obviously it may occasionally have been used since then; indeed, Google Books has a little more than [100 instances of *uncapable* in the nineteenth century](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uncapable%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1737,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22uncapable%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&start=110) and just over [30 in the twentieth century](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uncapable%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1737,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22uncapable%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&start=30), though some of these are likely spurious or duplicates.

Given its history and (somewhat) recent usage, I would say that *uncapable* is *not* "not a word". However, it is clear that *incapable* has won the battle for survival-of-the-lexically-fittest,  and I agree that you should generally prefer *incapable*, absent some really compelling reason to use *uncapable* (for example, if you were trying to enforce a different-than-expected definition, or wanted to sound archaic).

---

<sup>1</sup> "† unˈcapable, adj." *OED Online*. Oxford University Press, September 2016. Definition 2.

<sup>2</sup> "incapable, adj. and n." *OED Online*. Oxford University Press, September 2016. Defintion 5.